# How to determine if Powershell WhatIf intends to make changes programmatically

Tags: powershell, system-administration

I am looking for a way to programmatically determine if PowerShell wishes to make changes using the whatif flag. I have a set of scripts that implement the ShouldProcess, whatif only returns output if the script determines something is not in the desired state.

I would like PowerShell to alert me if whatif would like to make changes so a human can review the plan. However after reading the documentation I cannot find any suggestion that whatif returns if it wishes to make changes or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _if whatif would like to make changes_.. The `-WhatIf` switch is there to NOT make any changes. It simply reports what _would_ happen, so you or any other human can see what the code would do if it wasn't for the `-WhatIf` switch..

Comment: I should rephrase - I would like a programmatic way of detecting if whatif reports that something is going to happen.

Comment: Ah, then perhaps have a look at [ShouldProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.1#pscmdletshouldprocess)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but you could execute the command in a non-interactive context with `-Confirm` - if it throws any exceptions indicating `ShouldProcess` couldn't be called, you'll know you reached a potentially destructive code path:

```
# Create non-interactive sandbox for executing with `-Confirm`
$sandbox = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({Verb-Noun -Confirm})
$null = $sandbox.Invoke()
if($sandbox.HadErrors){
  if($sandbox.Streams.Error.Where({$_.Exception -is [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] -and $_.Exception.Message -match '*"ShouldProcess"*'})){
    # Code reached ShouldProcess
  }
}
```